# WSO2 - Problems while trying to START WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Following is the error when I try to start WSO2 server (on Ubuntu). Its a SQLite Database. Looking at the error, looks like it is DB related. What could have gone wrong? Kindly let me know some guidelines around how I can fix it :

```
testteam@gmcs:~/gauri/wso2am-2.1.0/bin$ bash wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/testteam/gauri/wso2am-2.1.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2017-08-21 11:50:23,345]  INFO - QpidBundleActivator Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,532]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,532]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.10.0-32-generic, amd64
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,532]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,532]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_131
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,533]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11,Oracle Corporation
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,533]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/testteam/gauri/wso2am-2.1.0
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,533]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/testteam/gauri/wso2am-2.1.0/tmp
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,533]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : testteam, en-IN, Asia/Kolkata
[2017-08-21 11:50:25,839]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2017-08-21 11:50:26,229]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2017-08-21 11:50:26,370]  INFO - ManagementModeConfigurationLoader CEP started in Single node mode
[2017-08-21 11:50:26,458]  INFO - TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2017-08-21 11:50:30,147] ERROR - DefaultRealm nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:401)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:263)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:355)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:839)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4064)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:280)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:222)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:991)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:827)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 7545 got 13 T90.I92" [50000-175]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:161)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:284)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:137)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.redo(PageStore.java:1535)
    at org.h2.store.PageLog.recover(PageLog.java:318)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1371)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:361)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:285)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2298)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:626)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:244)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:239)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:160)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:139)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:323)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:565)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:973)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 7545 got 13 T90.I92
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:231)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.checkRowCount(RegularTable.java:168)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:120)
    ... 57 more
[2017-08-21 11:50:30,165] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:273)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:322)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:263)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:401)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:355)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:839)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4064)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:280)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:222)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:991)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:827)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 7545 got 13 T90.I92" [50000-175]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:161)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:284)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:137)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.redo(PageStore.java:1535)
    at org.h2.store.PageLog.recover(PageLog.java:318)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1371)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:361)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:285)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2298)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:626)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:244)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:239)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:160)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:139)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:323)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:565)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:973)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowCount expected 7545 got 13 T90.I92
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:231)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.checkRowCount(RegularTable.java:168)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:120)
    ... 57 more
[2017-08-21 11:50:53,572]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

Comment: what is the product that you try to start? Why you wanna use SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

You are using API Manager 2.1 with SQLLite database. But, we haven't tested this database against this product. Also, from the logs, it seems you are using H2 database driver class.

Can you use SQLLite database driver class org.sqlite.JDBC and see?

Comment: Can you help me here >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860173/ora-12705-nls-lang-error-when-deploying-oracle-as-database-for-wso2-apim?noredirect=1#comment103997520_58860173